# Acrobat XI doesn't save javascript events

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, keyboard-events, acrobat

I am having a problem with adding custom keystroke and format scripts into a text field. As it is told in the documents, I right click the field and select properties, go to the format tab and select custom as the format catagory, click one of the edit buttons, write some javascript and click ok. But, nothing is saved. It turns back to the format tab with format category is none, just an empty window. Does anyone know what is causing this problem?

Comment: Which Acrobat version are you using?

Comment: version 11.0.08. pro trial